# Is there software or even device what could recognize specific voice and depending on that plays back predefined recording

Tags: voice-recognition

I am looking for device or software which will be able to recognize voice and based on voice will play back predefined media source through speakers. 
Google home came in to my mind, but googled a bit and didnt find is it includes such feature.

Thanks!
Z.

Comment: You can do it with an ESP32, if you can code. See https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/58509/arduino-voice-recognition

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for Voiceprint or Speaker Recognition capabilities.

If you are, you should probably go look at [THIS](https://github.com/ibillxia/VoicePrintReco) project.

I believe that the [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speaker-recognition/) stack has some capabilities in this space as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using your Android phone (and probably Apple) I can search for the [Google APP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) by typing "Voice Search", starting that APP (or leaving "OK Google" turned on), and saying: "Play [Insert song name here]" - the song is located and played.

First time through you may need to set it up and choose your preferred player, second time it simply plays the song automagically. You can cast it to your stereo if desired, you can also choose videos (and send it to your TV if the TV has the capability).

There is the ability to go to your device's storage and play your own songs instead of the version that Google guesses that you want (if you aren't specific enough).

With ***my*** phone there was nothing to buy or install, it Just Works™.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not exactly what I am looking for. 

I prefer not to use phone for this and it should work something like this: I record some kind of sound/voice, lets take for example dog barking. Then I can make rule, if dog barking is recognized then play that particular sound/voice etc.

Comment: Thanks for making that more clear, comments are temporary and subject to deletion. If you wish you could add that to your question - clairify the sentence: "... based on voice will play back predefined media ..." - or leave it as-is. --- If my answer has no value to your question I'm willing/going to delete it. Thanks for your reply.